# How to send a digital signed email or document from iphone ( iOS 8 )

Tags: ios, iphone, digital-signature

I need a way to create a digital signed document and send using a digital signed e-mail from my iPhone ( iOS 8 )

Any suggestions regarding apps are kindly appreciated

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into DocuSign. It's not a mobile dependant solution but it works.

I think they have an option for emailing the document as well.